# Convert number to string without any formating and using "." as floating point separator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis-express

When I do `12345.12345 + ""` I get `"12345,12345"` on my windows machine's IIS Express.

I need to convert the number to the standard representation that can be parsed by other programs, that is `XXXX.XXXX` - no spaces, no commas. How to do that?

Comment: change the culture settings for that app/printout..

Comment: I need the package to work independently no matter what the settings are. I can't control the client's server and I don't want to introduce another possible point of failure.

Comment: You can in your code.... read up on formatting and culture settings

Comment: You really shouldn't be using the `+` operator on a number and a string.

Comment: Just use the Convert.ToString with your number and pass the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture as second parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Convert.ToString method has an overload that allows a second parameter to be the CultureInfo used to create the string representation of your number. CultureInfo.InvariantCulture is the static class that contains the . as decimal separator. Putting all together your get

```
string myString = Convert.ToString(12345.12345, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Note that it will not work correctly with very large\very small numbers, because for them it will switch to scientific notation

Answer (score 1):

The functionality of `double.ToString()` should to the magic:

```
double number = 1234.1234;
string s = number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Did you try it with on a computer with a default culture using the comma as decimal separator for floating point numbers?

Comment: On an English Windows, maybe.

Comment: This method will suffer exactly the same problem that OP is having.

Answer (score 0):

This produces the required result:

```
Convert.ToString(12345.12345, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set the culture for your thread:

```
string lsOut = (1234.1234 + "").ToString();
Console.WriteLine(lsOut);

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.LCID);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = "";

lsOut = (1234.1234 + "").ToString();
Console.WriteLine(lsOut);
```

Output is (If `de-DE` is set first):

```
1234,1234
1234.1234
```